# Catching exceptions polymorphically

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, reference, virtual

Here is `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    B b(1,"two","three");
    try
    {
        f1(b);
    }
    catch(B& b_ref)
    {
        cout<<"Caught B&"<<endl;
        b_ref.print();
    }
    catch(A& a_ref)
    {
        cout<<"Caught A&"<<endl;
        a_ref.print();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is `f1()`:

```
void f1(A& subject)
{
    throw subject;
}
```

Information:

B inherits from A. `A::print()` is virtual, and is reimplemented in B. The catch that catches the exception is `catch(A& a_ref)`, which I guess makes sense, since the exceptions' static type (subject) is A&. BUT, why isn't `B:: print()` running? Is the dynamic type "lost"? Only `A::print()` runs in the line `a_ref.print();`.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Wow this came out totally unreadable. Please, look here for a comprehensable version of this post:
http://forums.devarticles.com/c-c-help-52/catching-exceptions-polymorphically-208759.html

Comment: I've reformatted your question :>

Comment: Fixed. Remember to indent the code with 4 spaces or  better still, highlight the code and press Ctrl + K

Answer (score 6):

`throw` only throws an object of the type of the expression which follows it. In this case, `subject` is of type `A&`, regardless of what the actual object is, so an `A` is thrown (note that references cannot be thrown, so a copy is made).

You can deal with this by adding a member function to your exception classes which throws the exception. As long as you implement this method in every class, the override which gets called will know the runtime type of the object and can `throw *this`.

http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401940

Comment: I did what you said and now it works as expected..I added the member function to A:
virtual void raise() { throw *this; }
and this member function to B:
void raise() { throw *this; }
So now, 'raise()' makes sure I throw the most derived object referenced to by A& subject, correct? It's weird no one's ever talked to us about this, only in regard to pointers. I guess the reason why it works with pointers is because, the pointer itself is copied, and I can still know what it points to dynamically..

Comment: Exactly, yes. It works with pointers because the pointer itself is the object thrown, whereas when you throw using a reference it's the referand which is thrown (and hence copied, and hence sliced).

Comment: Please note that you have to be very careful when throwing pointers. If you throw pointers to dynamically created objects it can be extremely hard to get the ownership semantics consistent. Throwing pointers to local objects usually incorrect and throwing pointers to global objects... well, implies you have global objects.

Comment: I'm aware of that pitfall. However, if the pointer was created in main(), say, and not dynamically (not with 'new'), there isn't any risk, is there?

Answer (score 6):

According to C++ standard 15.1/3:

> A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, called the exception object, the type of which is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand of throw...

So you create temporary object of type A, not B.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "`throw subject`" a new exception object is created based on the static type of the throw expression (`subject`). The fact that `subject` is a reference is irrelevant for the purposes of determining what object to throw. A new `A` object is copy constructed from `subject`. This copy (or possibly a copy of this copy) is the actual object that is caught.

Answer (score 4):

Catch blocks work polymorphically, but throw doesn't. When you say:

```
void f1(A& subject)
{
    throw subject;
}
```

you are throwing an A, although the thing passed to the function is a B.

Comment: That's nasty (slicing problem will apply). Learn something new every day.

Answer (score -1):

Because you catch by reference the object is 'sliced'.

If you really want polymorhpic behaviour, try using something like the pimpl idiom.

Comment: Not quite true; it is catching by value, not reference, that causes the 'slicing' problem, and that's not what's going on here.  It is rather that 'throw' doesn't consider the actual type of the object, just the static type. (see onebyone's answer).